# finite subsets of torsion-free groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Does there exist a torsion-free group $(G,.)$ with the following property?

There exists finite, non-empty subsets $S_1,S_2\subset G$ such that for all $s \in S_1.S_2$ there are at least two solutions to the equation $s=s_1.s_2$ where $s_1\in S_1$ and $s_2\in S_2$.

-

I imagine that such a group $(G,.)$ does exist. If you've found one, please could you explain how you constructed it also?

-

The motivation for this question is to prove that the group ring (for example over $\mathbb{Z}$) of any torsion-free group has no zero divisors, as conjectured by Kaplansky. If such $S_1$ and $S_2$ never exist then Kaplansky's conjecture would be true for lots of rings (any ring with no zero divisors in fact).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are the "unique product groups". Not every torsion-free group satisfies this property. See Promislow, S. David, A simple example of a torsion-free, nonunique product group. 
Bull. London Math. Soc. 20 (1988), no. 4, 302–304.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And googling finds lots more papers with many more examples and references. Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: In fact Promislow's example is somewhat better than others since in his example $S_1=S_2$. 

Comment: Strojnowski showed that you can always get $S_1 = S_2$ (see "A note on u.p. groups", Comm. Algebra, 1980)